# NullPointerException when calling self-written class

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I'm calling from one class another class. I can set values and get values when created an object (see Log) but there is lots of methods which throw an exception (see log as well). For example toasting something. If i put the code to toast something in the original class it works, if i try to call it, it doesnt work. In my code below these things which do not work are commented out (`// code...`).

Here is the Main.class:

```
public class Main extends Activity {
private MyMenu myMenu;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    myMenu = new MyMenu ();

    myMenu.setMyMenu (3, "some text");
    int number = myMenu.getMyMenuNumber();
    String text = myMenu.getMyMenuString();

    Log.d("LOG", "number is " + number + " and text is '" + text + "'.");

    try {
        Log.d ("LOG", "startMain error");
        //myMenu.startMain();
        startActivity(new Intent (this, Page1.class));
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        Log.d ("LOG", "putToast error");
        //myMenu.putToast();
        Toast.makeText(
                this, 
                "This is a toast", 
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    try {
        Log.d ("LOG", "inflateMenu error");
        //myMenu.inflateMenu(menu);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    try {
        Log.d ("LOG", "isOptionsButtonClicked error");
        //myMenu.isOptionsButtonClicked(item);
        switch (item.getItemId()) {     
        case R.id.feedback:
            startActivity(new Intent (this, Page1.class));
            break;
        case R.id.more_information:
            startActivity(new Intent (this, Page1.class));
            break;
        }
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

and this is MyMenu.class:

```
public class MyMenu extends Activity {
    int number;
    String text;

public MyMenu() {

}
public void setMyMenu (int number, String text) {
    this.number = number;
    this.text = text;
}
public int getMyMenuNumber () {
    return number;
}
public String getMyMenuString () {
    return text;
}

public void startMain () {
    startActivity(new Intent (this, Page1.class));
}

public void inflateMenu (Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
}
public void putToast () {
    Toast.makeText(
            this, 
            "This is a toast", 
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
    .show();
}
public void isOptionsButtonClicked (MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {     
    case R.id.feedback:
        startActivity(new Intent (this, Page1.class));
        break;
    case R.id.more_information:
        startActivity(new Intent (this, Page1.class));
        break;
    }
}
}
```

To stress it out again, running everything in Main.class works perfectly but calling the other classes doesnt work.

**UPDATE**

Here is parts of the Log/StackTrace:

```
05-15 08:13:13.502: DEBUG/LOG(546): inflateMenu error
05-15 08:13:13.513: WARN/System.err(546): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-15 08:13:13.522: WARN/System.err(546):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:80)
05-15 08:13:13.522: WARN/System.err(546):     at android.view.MenuInflater.inflate(MenuInflater.java:77)
05-15 08:13:13.522: WARN/System.err(546):     at com.test.MyMenu.inflateMenu(MyMenu.java:34)
05-15 08:13:13.533: WARN/System.err(546):     at com.test.Main.onCreateOptionsMenu(Main.java:52)
05-15 08:13:13.542: WARN/System.err(546):     at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2123)
05-15 08:13:13.542: WARN/System.err(546):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:305)
05-15 08:13:13.542: WARN/System.err(546):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onKeyDownPanel(PhoneWindow.java:550)
05-15 08:13:13.582: WARN/System.err(546):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onKeyDown(PhoneWindow.java:1192)
05-15 08:13:13.582: WARN/System.err(546):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1636)
05-15 08:13:13.582: WARN/System.err(546):     at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverKeyEventToViewHierarchy(ViewRoot.java:2368)
05-15 08:13:13.582: WARN/System.err(546):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleFinishedEvent(ViewRoot.java:2338)
05-15 08:13:13.582: WARN/System.err(546):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1641)
05-15 08:13:13.582: WARN/System.err(546):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-15 08:13:13.592: WARN/System.err(546):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-15 08:13:13.592: WARN/System.err(546):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
05-15 08:13:13.602: WARN/System.err(546):     at     java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-15 08:13:13.602: WARN/System.err(546):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-15 08:13:13.602: WARN/System.err(546):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
05-15 08:13:13.602: WARN/System.err(546):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
05-15 08:13:13.602: WARN/System.err(546):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and:

```
05-15 08:13:03.592: DEBUG/LOG(546): putToast error
05-15 08:13:03.612: WARN/System.err(546): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-15 08:13:03.621: WARN/System.err(546):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:80)
05-15 08:13:03.633: WARN/System.err(546):     at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:89)
05-15 08:13:03.633: WARN/System.err(546):     at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:231)
05-15 08:13:03.633: WARN/System.err(546):     at com.test.MyMenu.putToast(MyMenu.java:37)
05-15 08:13:03.641: WARN/System.err(546):     at com.test.Main.onCreate(Main.java:37)
05-15 08:13:03.641: WARN/System.err(546):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-15 08:13:03.652: WARN/System.err(546):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
05-15 08:13:03.652: WARN/System.err(546):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
05-15 08:13:03.652: WARN/System.err(546):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
05-15 08:13:03.661: WARN/System.err(546):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
05-15 08:13:03.661: WARN/System.err(546):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-15 08:13:03.671: WARN/System.err(546):     at    android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-15 08:13:03.671: WARN/System.err(546):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
05-15 08:13:03.671: WARN/System.err(546):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-15 08:13:03.683: WARN/System.err(546):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-15 08:13:03.683: WARN/System.err(546):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
05-15 08:13:03.691: WARN/System.err(546):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
05-15 08:13:03.691: WARN/System.err(546):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

hope that helps!

**UDATE 2**

Here is the requested Page1.class. But again everything runs fine when i do not use the MyMenu.class.

```
public class Page1 extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.page1);
}

}
```

Furthermore you can download the android project from microsoft's/windows live skydrive:
http://cid-f45ce92851885387.office.live.com/browse.aspx/Stackoverflow

Comment: First of all if something is going wrong you should put PrintStackTrace to help others find bug in your code.
Cheers!

Comment: The exception location is not in the classes you pasted here - on the call to myMenu.startMain(), myMenu is definitely not null, and in the startMain method no object is accessed in a way that can cause a NPE. This is similar in other calls, so my guess is that the Activity superclass is at fault. Of course, the stack trace would tell us for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't figure out why you're delegating this method below to other activity:

```
public void startMain () {
   startActivity(new Intent (this, Page1.class)); // this <- here is problem
}
```

I suppose that's because of bad desing. Don't do that. Use Intents. Pass data between Activities in Intents in Bundles. 
In your case you didn't pass Context to MyMenu Activity. MyMenu hasn't got instance of Application Context therefore you're getting NPE.

**response for comment:**
You can do static startMain method, of course. But pay attention to what is 'this' in new Intent(this, Page1.class). You should pass Context of Activity from which you're starting the new Activity.

```
public static void startMain (Activity context) {
   context.startActivity(new Intent (context, Page1.class));
}
```

Comment: This is just an example. My methods contain lots more lines of code. That is why I want to put it into another class and call it whenever I need it from any class.
So how do I use Intents? How do I pass Context to `MyMenu.class` on?

Comment: static does not work (Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method startActivity(Intent) from the type Activity) and when I put `public void startMain (Context context) {startActivity(new Intent (context, Page1.class));}` in my `MainMenu.class` and `myMenu.startMain(myMenu);` in `Main.class` it does not work either.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. Method chenged.

Comment: Tried it but still it does not work and the error log is very similar to those posted above. So in my `Main.class` I have put this: `MyMenu.startMain(myMenu);` is that correct? Do I have to put something else in these brackets? Using your updated method of course!

Comment: No, not myMenu! It hasn't got instance of application context. `MyMenu.startMain(this);` It works, but it's still bad design. Read about Intents.

Comment: Works! Thanks! This is now in `MyMenu.class`: `public static void isOptionsButtonClicked (Activity context, MenuItem item) {
  switch (item.getItemId()) {  
  case R.id.feedback:
   context.startActivity(new Intent (context, Page1.class));
   break;
  case R.id.more_information:
   context.startActivity(new Intent (context, Page1.class));
   break;
  }` or `public static void inflateMenu (Activity context, Menu menu) {
  context.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);}` or `public static void startMain (Activity context) {
     context.startActivity(new Intent (context, Page1.class));}`

Comment: Appreciate your help dziobas!